# unable to display font on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

I was able to create a site on my Mac using the system installed .otf fonts. When the site was uploaded to the host, the correct fonts were not displaying in IE. I used Brush Script Std and tried to convert it to .eot using a font generator but Font Squirrel was having none of it. It is an Adobe font. I did find one or two generator sites that returned a file but I can't seem to get the hosting server to recognize it. The file control panel seems to recognize the other fonts but not .eot.

[image]

The following is my style rule:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Brush Script Std'; src: url('./Exported Fonts/Brush Script Std/BrushScriptStd.otf'), url('./Exported Fonts/Brush Script Std/BrushScriptStd.eot') }

h1 {font-size: 64px; font-family: 'Brush Script Std';
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get IE to display my font?

Comment: ok, I was able to download a .woff available font from Font Squirrel and upload it to the host server. When I tested it in IE, the font displayed properly. Once more, I converted my Brush Script.otf font to .woff and uploaded that file to the server. When I tested it, it wouldn't render. I even changed the content to confirm the revision but IE refused to render the font. All other browsers cooperate. The appearance of the content nor the font reflected any change which leads me to believe that a restriction in IE is interfering. I hate IE.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem. My hosting service must have been having problems because my changes weren't taking affect. I'm all set.